# Is there a way to MQ put multiline string data?

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

We have a C++ application which reads from IBM MQ queues and expects data in following format

```
"textA
textB
textC"
```

We have our own testing tool which reads input data in `"textA\r\ntextB\r\ntextC\r\n"` and replaces `"\\r\\n"` with actual `"\r\n"` characters and puts onto MQ.

What i am looking for is some third party tool like IBM websphere MQ or amqsput to put multiline data with the actual CRLF characters on to MQ.

Comment: Why you can't use IBM tools? You can even compile it's for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the data in a file then there are lots of tools that will put a file as a message to an IBM MQ queue.  Here a list: http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools.html